# C# Add-In for MS Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, ms-project

I coded an add-in for MS Project but I having some issues.
In this add-in I have a loop that add tasks, but when my task has a predecessor that my loop doesnt created yet, the MS Project add this task automaticaly.

Lets supose my loop is creating task 5 and it have task 25 as predecessor.
Ms Project will create the task 25 at position 6 (right after that one the looping is adding)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj = this.Application.Projects.Add();
MSProject.Task newTask = pj.Tasks.Add("New Task", i);
newTask.Predecessors = "25";
```

The major problem is my task 6 (from loop) has task 5 as predecessor. This case give me a error (infinite loop of tasks).

Is there any way to add multiple tasks? Without loop?
Or configure the add tasks from Predecessor.

Tks

Comment: Yes, of *COURSE* you can add multiple tasks to a project.  With or without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the all tasks and then add the task dependencies in other loop.
It look like that:

```
     for(int i=0;i<30;++i)//add all tasks
     {
       project.tasks.add(...);
       ...//todo other things
     }

     for(int i=0;i<project.tasks.count;++i)//add preprocesser for task
     {
       project.tasks[i].dependencies=...;         
     }
```

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I doing. But 2 loopings to do 1 thing? Sounds wrong to me.